Repainting/Recalculating when Using Multi-Timeframe Analysis
Still learning, I cannot find the reason why it repaints using the MTF built-in feature, if the page is reloaded then the correct calculation will be plotted, but only then.
So for example 1M chart and the indicator is on the 5MIN, recalculation each 30 min. Correct initial plot should start at 8:08, and the incorrect one (without page reloading)  8:06.
is it a bug of Pinescript? or what went wrong?
feel free to use the script if you like is derived from another OSS.
I appreciate any assistance.
//@version=5
indicator('MTF VWAP', overlay=true, max_boxes_count = 500, timeframe = "", timeframe_gaps = false) 

resolution1 = input.timeframe("D", "VWAP resolution")
source      = input.source(ohlc4, "VWAP source")
session1    = input.session(defval = "0730-1200", title = "Standard Opening")

///
H1 = time(resolution1, session1)
open_bar(t) => na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t ? 1 : 0
tf_switch1 = ta.change(open_bar(H1)) > 0
[_vwap, _stdevUpper, _] = ta.vwap(source, tf_switch1, 1)
color1 = close > _vwap ? color.green : color.red

/// Bands
offset = 0
BANDS_GROUP = "Bands Settings"
CALC_MODE_TOOLTIP = "Determines the units used to calculate the distance of the bands. When 'Percentage' is selected, a multiplier of 1 means 1%."
calcModeInput = input.string("Standard Deviation", "Bands Calculation Mode", options = ["Standard Deviation", "Percentage"], group = BANDS_GROUP, tooltip = CALC_MODE_TOOLTIP)
showBand_1 = input(true, title = "", group = BANDS_GROUP, inline = "band_1")
bandMult_1 = input.float(1.0, title = "Bands Multiplier #1", group = BANDS_GROUP, inline = "band_1", step = 0.5, minval=0)
showBand_2 = input(false, title = "", group = BANDS_GROUP, inline = "band_2")
bandMult_2 = input.float(2.0, title = "Bands Multiplier #2", group = BANDS_GROUP, inline = "band_2", step = 0.5, minval=0)
showBand_3 = input(false, title = "", group = BANDS_GROUP, inline = "band_3")
bandMult_3 = input.float(3.0, title = "Bands Multiplier #3", group = BANDS_GROUP, inline = "band_3", step = 0.5, minval=0)

if barstate.islast and ta.cum(volume) == 0
    runtime.error("No volume is provided by the data vendor.")

float vwapValue = na
float upperBandValue1 = na
float lowerBandValue1 = na
float upperBandValue2 = na
float lowerBandValue2 = na
float upperBandValue3 = na
float lowerBandValue3 = na

vwapValue := _vwap
stdevAbs = _stdevUpper - _vwap
bandBasis = calcModeInput == "Standard Deviation" ? stdevAbs : _vwap * 0.01
upperBandValue1 := _vwap + bandBasis * bandMult_1
lowerBandValue1 := _vwap - bandBasis * bandMult_1
upperBandValue2 := _vwap + bandBasis * bandMult_2
lowerBandValue2 := _vwap - bandBasis * bandMult_2
upperBandValue3 := _vwap + bandBasis * bandMult_3
lowerBandValue3 := _vwap - bandBasis * bandMult_3

plot(_vwap, color = tf_switch1 ? na :color1, linewidth = 1)

upperBand_1 = plot(upperBandValue1, title="Upper Band #1", color=color.green, offset=offset, display = showBand_1 ? display.all : display.none)
lowerBand_1 = plot(lowerBandValue1, title="Lower Band #1", color=color.green, offset=offset, display = showBand_1 ? display.all : display.none)
fill(upperBand_1, lowerBand_1, title="Bands Fill #1", color= color.new(color.green, 95)    , display = showBand_1 ? display.all : display.none)

upperBand_2 = plot(upperBandValue2, title="Upper Band #2", color=color.olive, offset=offset, display = showBand_2 ? display.all : display.none)
lowerBand_2 = plot(lowerBandValue2, title="Lower Band #2", color=color.olive, offset=offset, display = showBand_2 ? display.all : display.none)
fill(upperBand_2, lowerBand_2, title="Bands Fill #2", color= color.new(color.olive, 95)    , display = showBand_2 ? display.all : display.none)

upperBand_3 = plot(upperBandValue3, title="Upper Band #3", color=color.teal, offset=offset, display = showBand_3 ? display.all : display.none)
lowerBand_3 = plot(lowerBandValue3, title="Lower Band #3", color=color.teal, offset=offset, display = showBand_3 ? display.all : display.none)
fill(upperBand_3, lowerBand_3, title="Bands Fill #3", color= color.new(color.teal, 95)    , display = showBand_3 ? display.all : display.none)



MTF should not be repainting if the actual script doesnt.
